# Ionic material List is not Performing well in ng-repeat

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on Ionic floating menu button .It is working fine but my problem is that when I click on button + then i don't want to click on **click me** button means i don't want to click on click me button when menu is open (Req1.png)[image] .

And second requirement is that when **-** is showing then color will be faded [image]
Check my **codepen.io/anujsphinx/pen/jVLRXa**

Comment: I run your codepen, no background appear and I can click click me button when I click on + button

Comment: Not clear with your question, please elaborate more.

Comment: when the menu open, you want the background disabled? which means nothing is clickable? if its that, get the class`active` from the menu and use some blockui from ionic or angular, they might have some directive for that.

Comment: can you do this with css or JS and update codepen?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this.

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('ion-floating-menu', [])

            .directive('ionFloatingButton', ionFloatingButton)
            .directive('ionFloatingMenu', ionFloatingMenu)
            .directive('ionFloatingItem', ionFloatingItem)
            .factory('$ionicBackdropIon', $ionicBackdropIon);


    function ionFloatingButton() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                click: '&?',
                buttonColor: '@?',
                buttonClass: '@?',
                icon: '@?',
                iconColor: '@?',
                hasFooter: '=?',
                isCentered: '=?',
                text: '@?',
                textClass: '@?',
                bottom: '@?'},
            template: '<ul ng-click="click()" id="floating-button" ng-class="{\'center\': isCentered}" ng-style="{\'bottom\' : \'{{bottom}}\' }">' +
                    '<li ng-class="buttonClass" ng-style="{\'background-color\': buttonColor }">' +
                    '<a><span ng-if="text" class="label-container"><span class="label" ng-class="textClass" ng-bind="text"></span></span><i class="icon menu-icon" ng-class="{ \'{{icon}}\' : true}" ng-style="{\'color\': iconColor }"></i></a>' +
                    '</li>' +
                    '</ul>',
            replace: false,
            transclude: true,
            controller: ionFloatingButtonCtrl
        };
    }

    ionFloatingButtonCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function ionFloatingButtonCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.buttonColor = $scope.buttonColor || '#2AC9AA';
        $scope.icon = $scope.icon || 'ion-plus';
        $scope.iconColor = $scope.iconColor || '#fff';
        $scope.hasFooter = $scope.hasFooter || false;
        $scope.isCentered = $scope.isCentered || false;

        if ($scope.hasFooter) {
            $scope.bottom = '60px';
        } else {
            $scope.bottom = $scope.bottom || '20px';
        }
    }

    function ionFloatingMenu() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                menuOpenColor: '@?',
                menuOpenIcon: '@?',
                menuOpenIconColor: '@?',
                menuColor: '@?',
                menuIcon: '@?',
                menuIconColor: '@?',
                hasFooter: '=?',
                backdrop: '=?',
                bottom: '@?'
            },
            template: '<ul id="floating-menu"  \n\
                            ng-style="{\'bottom\' : \'{{bottom}}\'}" \n\
                            ng-class="{\'active\' : isOpen}" \n\
                            ng-click="open()">' +
                    '<div ng-transclude></div>' +
                    '<span><li class="menu-button icon menu-icon" ng-class="icon" ng-style="{\'background-color\' : buttonColor, \'color\': iconColor}"></li></span>' +
                    '</ul>',
            replace: false,
            transclude: true,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude)
            {
                element.find('div').replaceWith(transclude());
            },
            controller: ionFloatingMenuCtrl
        };
    }

    function ionFloatingItem() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            require: ['^ionFloatingMenu'],
            scope: {
                click: '&?',
                icon: '@',
                iconColor: '@?',
                buttonColor: '@?',
                buttonClass: '@?',
                iconImagePath: '@?',
                iconImageClass: '@?',
                text: '@?',
                textClass: '@?'},
            template:
                    '<li ng-click="click()" ng-class="buttonClass" ng-style="{\'background-color\': buttonColor }">' +
                    '<span ng-if="text" class="label-container"><span class="label" ng-class="textClass" ng-bind="text"></span></span>' +
                    '<img ng-if="iconImagePath" class="menu-icon" ng-class="iconImageClass" src="{{iconImagePath}}"/>' +
                    '<i ng-if="!iconImagePath" class="icon menu-icon" ng-class="{ \'{{icon}}\' : true}" ng-style="{\'color\': iconColor }"></i>' +
                    '</li>',
            replace: false,
            controller: ionFloatingItemCtrl
        };
    }

    ionFloatingMenuCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$ionicBackdropIon','$ionicBackdrop'];
    function ionFloatingMenuCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $ionicBackdropIon,$ionicBackdrop) {
        $scope.isOpen = false;
        $scope.open = function () {
            $scope.isOpen = !$scope.isOpen;
            if ($scope.isOpen) {
              $ionicBackdrop.retain();
                $scope.setOpen();
            } else {
              $ionicBackdrop.release();
                $scope.setClose();
            }
        };
        $scope.setOpen = function () {
            $scope.buttonColor = menuOpenColor;
            $scope.icon = menuOpenIcon;
            $scope.iconColor = menuOpenIconColor;

            if (backdrop) {
                $ionicBackdropIon.retain();
            }
            $rootScope.$broadcast('floating-menu:open');
        };
        $scope.setClose = function () {
            $scope.buttonColor = menuColor;
            $scope.icon = menuIcon;
            $scope.iconColor = menuIconColor;
            if (backdrop) {
                $ionicBackdropIon.release();
            }
            $rootScope.$broadcast('floating-menu:close');
        };
        var menuColor = $scope.menuColor || '#2AC9AA';
        var menuIcon = $scope.menuIcon || 'ion-plus';
        var menuIconColor = $scope.menuIconColor || '#fff';
        var menuOpenColor = $scope.menuOpenColor || '#2AC9AA';
        var menuOpenIcon = $scope.menuOpenIcon || 'ion-minus';
        var menuOpenIconColor = $scope.menuOpenIconColor || '#fff';
        var backdrop = $scope.backdrop || false;
        $scope.setClose();
        $scope.hasFooter = $scope.hasFooter || false;
        if ($scope.hasFooter) {
            $scope.bottom = '60px';
        } else {
            $scope.bottom = $scope.bottom || '20px';
        }

    }

    ionFloatingItemCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function ionFloatingItemCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.buttonColor = $scope.buttonColor || '#2AC9AA';
        $scope.iconColor = $scope.iconColor || '#fff';
    }


    $ionicBackdropIon.$inject = ['$document', '$timeout', '$$rAF', '$rootScope'];
    function $ionicBackdropIon($document, $timeout, $$rAF, $rootScope) {
        var el = angular.element('<div class="backdrop">');
        var backdropHolds = 0;


        var a = angular.element(document.querySelector('ion-content')).append(el[0]);

        return {
            /**
             * @ngdoc method
             * @name $ionicBackdrop#retain
             * @description Retains the backdrop.
             */
            retain: retain,
            /**
             * @ngdoc method
             * @name $ionicBackdrop#release
             * @description
             * Releases the backdrop.
             */
            release: release,
            getElement: getElement,
            // exposed for testing
            _element: el
        };

        function retain() {
            backdropHolds++;
            if (backdropHolds === 1) {
                el.addClass('visible');
                $rootScope.$broadcast('backdrop.shown');
                $$rAF(function () {
                    // If we're still at >0 backdropHolds after async...
                    if (backdropHolds >= 1)
                        el.addClass('active');
                });
            }
        }
        function release() {
            if (backdropHolds === 1) {
                el.removeClass('active');
                $rootScope.$broadcast('backdrop.hidden');
                $timeout(function () {
                    // If we're still at 0 backdropHolds after async...
                    if (backdropHolds === 0)
                        el.removeClass('visible');
                }, 400, false);
            }
            backdropHolds = Math.max(0, backdropHolds - 1);
        }

        function getElement() {
            return el;
        }

    }
})();


angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic','ion-floating-menu'])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$ionicBackdrop) {
 
  $scope.test=function(){
    alert("clicked me");
  };
  $scope.myEvent=function(){
    alert("second clicked");
  };
   $scope.first=function(){
    alert("first clicked");
  };
});
```

```css
/*!
 * Copyright 2016 PREGIOTEK
 * http://pregiotek.com/
 *
 * ion-floating-menu
 * Material UI-like Floating Action Button and Menu for Ionic applications.
 *
 * By @ennedigi
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license. Please see LICENSE for more information.
 *
 */

/*floating-button*/

#floating-button {
    bottom: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 20px;
    z-index : 9999;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#floating-button.center{
    margin-left: auto !important; 
    margin-right: auto !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
}

#floating-button>li {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
}

#floating-button a {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

#floating-button .icon.menu-icon{
    font-size: 20px;
}

#floating-button li span.label{
    margin-right: 2px;
    color: gray;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0.5px 2px 2px 0.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


#floating-button li span.label-container{
    margin-right: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    right: 75px;
    width: 400px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 15px;
}



/*floating-menu*/

#floating-menu {
    position: fixed;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#floating-menu .center{
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
}

#floating-menu .icon.menu-icon{
    font-size: 20px;
}

#floating-menu img.menu-icon{
    font-size: 20px;
}

#floating-menu li i{
    font-size: 20px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#floating-menu li.menu-button {
    z-index: 9999;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#floating-menu li{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0.5px;
    top: 0.5px;
    width: 98%;
    height: 98%;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
}

#floating-menu li span.label{
    margin-right: 2px;
    color: gray;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0.5px 2px 2px 0.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


#floating-menu li span.label-container{
    margin-right: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    right: 75px;
    width: 400px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#floating-menu.active span.label-container{
    visibility: visible;
}


#floating-menu.active li{
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    top: 0;
}

/*#floating-menu li {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}*/

#floating-menu ion-floating-item > li  {
    transition: all .3s;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: .3s;
}

#floating-menu.active ion-floating-item:nth-child(1) > li {
    transform: translateY(-70px);
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-70px);
    transition-delay: 0ms; -webkit-transition-delay: 0ms;
}
#floating-menu.active ion-floating-item:nth-child(2) > li {
    transform: translateY(-140px);
     -webkit-transform:translateY(-140px);
    transition-delay: 50ms; -webkit-transition-delay: 50ms;
}
#floating-menu.active ion-floating-item:nth-child(3) > li {
    transform: translateY(-210px);
     -webkit-transform:translateY(-210px);
    transition-delay: 100ms; -webkit-transition-delay: 100ms;
}
#floating-menu.active ion-floating-item:nth-child(4) > li {
    transform: translateY(-280px);
     -webkit-transform:translateY(-280px);
    transition-delay: 150ms; -webkit-transition-delay: 150ms;
}
#floating-menu.active ion-floating-item:nth-child(5) > li {
    transform: translateY(-350px);
     -webkit-transform:translateY(-350px);
    transition-delay: 160ms; -webkit-transition-delay: 160ms;
}
#floating-menu.active ion-floating-item:nth-child(6) > li {
    transform: translateY(-420px);
     -webkit-transform:translateY(-420px);
    transition-delay: 170ms; -webkit-transition-delay: 170ms;
}
#floating-menu.active ion-floating-item:nth-child(7) > li {
    transform: translateY(-490px);
     -webkit-transform:translateY(-490px);
    transition-delay: 180ms; -webkit-transition-delay: 180ms;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">  
    <title>Toggle</title>
    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl"> 
    HI
    <input type="button" value ="click me" ng-click="test()" />
<!--     <button type="button" value="Click me" ></button>  -->
    </ion-content>  
  <ion-floating-menu>
    <ion-floating-item icon="ion-camera" ng-click="first()" text="Add Contact"></ion-floating-item>
    <ion-floating-item icon="ion-person" ng-click="myEvent()" text="My Contact"></ion-floating-item>
</ion-floating-menu>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks pushkar .It is working but one issue is that when i am clicking on screen then then Add contact function and my contact function is clicking on background too.,